# Why trash folder got empty automatically?

Tags: trash

Yesterday I move some of my WordPress product to trash, and keep only 4 products available.

Today I open my site, all trash products was not there? But the 4 products still there.

I don't know are them deleted automatically? 
What happen, please advice me?

Answer (score 1):

Check the value for the constant `EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS`. With this constant can you control how long is the time to save in trash before delete automatically. Check at first the `wp-config.php` for this constant, maybe is set in your installation for a small value. The [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Trash_status) write more about the constant and his possibilities.

Also it is possible to change the default via hooks, like `pre_delete_post`. A good point to debug is the [function `wp_delete_post()` in `post.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/fe0b8a2aaf49ff5f33a866309ed8730fd7675674/wp-includes/post.php#L2425).

But you write about 'products', maybe you have active a custom post type there add this post type and the enhancement, the plugin have a option for the function, timestamp to delete this post type Product.

Comment: i am sorry i can't understand you well, i will repeat my question again

the trash got empty? is this due to new option applied or failure happen 

before the trash item didn't deleted even it stay for 1 year 

the day before the accident
1. I install a new plugin for justify and underline 
2. Configure the setting of Yoast plugin 
3. Delete cash by my cashing plugin 

i doubt that one of the following causing the problem, or i make empty trash by mistake 

Really i feeling doubt

Comment: I can't get a solid answer. It give a lot of point to check this and solve it. But my answer point you to the possibilities to check this. WP remove all items in the trash on default after 30 days, but each plugin, definition of the constant can change this.